# Passing formdata in object | Axios

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to passing formdata and other values to an axios api but can't access the formData in the backend anymore:

Like this it works:

```
  uploadFiles(formData, schema) {
    console.log("Uploading files...", ...formData);

    return instance
      .post(`upload`, formData)
      .then(response => console.log(response.status))
  }
```

But trying to handle multiple parameters like this doesn't:

```
  uploadFiles(formData, schema) {
    console.log("Uploading files...", ...formData);

    return instance
      .post(`upload`, {
        formData,
        schema
      })
      .then(response => console.log(response.status))
  }
```

How would I access the formData in the backend?
I can't access it like `req.files` anymore. And `req.body.formData` is empty.

Comment: Okay, what data do you provide in schema?

Comment: @Asimple It's just a string.

Comment: formData is FormData object?
You can just add schema to it: `formData.append('schema', schema);`. And send it as you did before.

Comment: @Asimple, that's a way. I'll try it. But it must be possible to send a data Object with formData included, isnt it?

Comment: As i remember axios will parse object as JSON automatically.
so you can't send files in this way

Comment: @Asimple All right, that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: you should add this edit to your answer @Asimple so Timo can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i remember axios will parse object as JSON automatically. so you can't send files in this way.
You can pass schema in FormData:

```
uploadFiles(formData, schema) {
    console.log("Uploading files...", ...formData);
    formData.append('schema', schema);

    return instance
      .post(`upload`, formData)
      .then(response => console.log(response.status))
  }
```

(Posted answer from comments here)